# Module 'TOCropViewController' not found inside the Pod

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I'm trying to install [IRLDocumentScanner](https://github.com/charlymr/IRLDocumentScanner) in my `Objective C` project using `Pods`.

Once I execute the command: `pod install`, I get this:

```
pod install Analyzing dependencies 
Downloading dependencies 
Using IRLDocumentScanner (0.3.1) 
Using TOCropViewController (2.3.6) 
Generating Pods project 
Integrating client project Sending stats
```

Now, I know that those `pods` are successfully installed, but when I compile my project, I get this error:

> Module 'TOCropViewController' not found

But, not in my project. The error happens just inside the pod, just in the `IRLScannerViewController.h` (this is not my `ViewController` is a controller from the pod).

Someone has an idea about how to fix it?

Comment: Hi I am also facing the same problem. Did you find any solution?@JESERRANO

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of doubts about an unofficial package like this have this type of bugs, more if you think about the number of users that currently are using this version, updated 2 years ago.

Maybe the problem is related with other package, or controller in your project with the same name producing an error, also, try to remove the dependency and verify that your project doesn't have any broken dependency or any error before the installation of the `pod`